# How do I handle saving data in my iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, save, nsuserdefaults, updates

My application needs to save several information about the user therefore I have planned methods to achieve this target. I managed this step by saving those information in two different location but I'm starting doubt about this, let me explain better:

- **Tutorial status**. This kind of information support (as you guessed) the tutorial status, marking as accomplished those completed by the user in order to avoid to show over and over again the same tutorial. The way I handle this information is by saving into `NSUserDefaults`.
- **Configuration**. This kind of information contains the user configuration (a sort of little profile). This time the way I handle this information is by saving into a file called "UserData.plist" inside `documentsPath` (code below).

  ```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *PLISTPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserData.plist"];
  ```

I'm creating the application in order to be ready to some updates. During those updates I don't want the user to lose any of those saved data. Am I doing something wrong or confused? Should I save everything inside `NSUserDefaults`?.

Comment: The user defaults will be maintained until the app is deleted. So the way you have it should be fine. I'd be adding in a way so the user an skip the tutorial as well.

Comment: @dogCoffee Ok, so I need to save the configuration in the `NSUserDefaults` too :)

Comment: May as well keep it simple if thats all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Using `NSUserDefaults` to save tutorial status is ok. Not very clear what you mean by `"user configuration"` ? Is it some sensitive data (password, email) ? If yes than it's not good to save it in a `plist` without encryption.

2) `User Defaults` is not deleted when app is updated.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Let me explain what I meant: during the configuration the users will compile some field with information about his studies. "Math: Level 9", "History: Level 10", "Science: Level 2". However, nothing sensitive. I just saved in a different part in order to have a file containing all of this information divided from the other.

Comment: Do you suggest me to save even those data inside the `NSUserDefaults ` or using different method?

Comment: You can save such kind of info in NSUserDefaults. But for example if your app will support multiple accounts then it will be more elegant to save them in a database (sqlite or core data)

Comment: Nice! This is my first app and I never used Core Data. I'm gonna take a look ;) Thanks again!